# What will be the correct angle to get the correct shape in clockwise direction

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image]

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QByteArray,QDataStream, QIODevice,pyqtSlot, QMimeData, QPointF, QPoint, Qt, QRect,QTimer,QLineF, QEvent,QRectF)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor,QDrag, QPainter, QPixmap,QFont,QFontMetrics,QBrush, QLinearGradient, QIcon, QPen, QPainterPath, QTransform,QCursor,QMouseEvent,QClipboard
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QGraphicsTextItem,QStyleOptionGraphicsItem,QStyle,QGraphicsItemGroup,QErrorMessage, QSizePolicy,QShortcut, QScrollArea, QPushButton,QLineEdit, QMainWindow,QInputDialog, QGraphicsPathItem,QDialog, QVBoxLayout,QGraphicsItem,QStatusBar,QTextEdit, QAction,QMenu, qApp,QSplitter, QButtonGroup, QToolButton, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QLabel, QGraphicsScene, QWidget
import importlib

class GraphicsSceneClass(QGraphicsScene):
    global selectedObjType
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsSceneClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gridOn = 0
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            sampleTransform = QTransform()
            objectAtMouse = self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), sampleTransform)

            if objectAtMouse and event.button()== Qt.LeftButton:
                objectAtMouse.setSelected(True)
                pass
            elif objectAtMouse==None and event.button()==Qt.RightButton:
                # pass
                self.grid = self.TargPosForLine(event.scenePos(), "ForLine")
            self.grid = self.TargPosForLine(event.scenePos(), "ForLine")
            opt=QStyleOptionGraphicsItem()
            opt.State=QStyle.State_None
            painter=QPainter()
            painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
            painter.setBrush(Qt.green)
            painter.drawRect(self.grid.x(),self.grid.y(),16,16)
    def TargPosForLine(self, position, mode):

        clicked_column = int((position.y() // 16)) * 16
        clicked_row = int((position.x() // 16)) * 16
        if clicked_column < 0:
            clicked_column = 0
        if clicked_row < 0:
            clicked_row = 0
        if(mode == "ForRect"):
            return QRect(clicked_row, clicked_column,16,16)
        elif(mode == "ForLine"):
            return QPointF(clicked_row,clicked_column)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # self.DeselectItems()
        pass
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    global selectedObjType
    # global item
    def __init__(self,):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.createToolbars()

        self.scene = GraphicsSceneClass()
        MainWindow.obj = self.scene
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        # self.view.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.view.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
        self.widg = QWidget()
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.widg.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.obj=None
    #


    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        contextMenu = QMenu(self)

        Cutaction = contextMenu.addAction("Cut")
        Coaction = contextMenu.addAction("Copy")
        Paaction = contextMenu.addAction("Paste")
        Propaction = contextMenu.addAction("draw1")
        Propaction1=contextMenu.addAction("draw2")
        quitAct = contextMenu.addAction("quit")
        action = contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action == quitAct:
            self.close()

        elif action == Propaction:
            objectDrop = QGraphicsPathItem()
            painterPath = QPainterPath()
            painterPath.moveTo(10, 6)
            painterPath.lineTo(10 + 44.3479, 6)
            painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 6 - 4, 4, 4, 270, 90)
            painterPath.lineTo(10 + 44.3479 - 2, 6 - 4)
            painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 6 - 6, 4, 4, 0, 90)
            painterPath.lineTo(10, 0)
            gradient = QLinearGradient(1, 1, 1, 5)
            gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(Qt.gray))
            gradient.setColorAt(0.5, QColor(192, 192, 192, 255))
            gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(Qt.darkGray))
            painterPath.closeSubpath()
            objectDrop.setPos(self.scene.grid)
            objectDrop.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
            objectDrop.setPath(painterPath)
            objectDrop.setBrush(QBrush(gradient))
            objectDrop._position = QPointF(self.scene.grid)
            print("line", self.scene.grid)
            objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
            objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            objectDrop._type1 = "line"
            self.scene.addItem(objectDrop)
            print(objectDrop)
        elif action==Propaction1:
            objectDrop = QGraphicsPathItem()
            painterPath = QPainterPath()
            painterPath.moveTo(10, 0)
            painterPath.lineTo(10 + 44.3479, 0)
            painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 0 - 4, 4, 4, 270, 90)
            painterPath.lineTo(10 + 44.3479 - 2, 0 - 4)
            painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 0 - 6, 4, 4, 0, 90)
            painterPath.lineTo(10, 6)
            gradient = QLinearGradient(1, 1, 1, 5)
            gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(Qt.gray))
            gradient.setColorAt(0.5, QColor(192, 192, 192, 255))
            gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(Qt.darkGray))
            painterPath.closeSubpath()
            objectDrop.setPos(self.scene.grid)
            objectDrop.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
            objectDrop.setPath(painterPath)
            objectDrop.setBrush(QBrush(gradient))
            objectDrop._position=QPointF(self.scene.grid)
            print("line",self.scene.grid)
            objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
            objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            objectDrop._type1 = "line"
            self.scene.addItem(objectDrop)
            print(objectDrop)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    mainWindow.show()        
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I need help in arcTo function of Qpainterpath.I have added the images of the painterpath code which i have mentioned here.

In first image i have drawn the pathitem in counter clockwise direction.
In second image I have drawn the pathitem in clockwise direction and it looks like twisted one.

I have tried by changing the angle mentioned in arcTo with negative sign.But it is not giving the perfect item like in first image.

What will be the correct angle to get the correct shape in clockwise direction

Comment: You should use `QTransform` to rotate a `QPainterPath`.

Comment: The arcs in item2 have different bounding boxes from those in item1 (they are shifted vertically by 6 pixels). They should be the same in both cases. To draw an arc in opposite direction you need to replace something like `path.arcTo(x,y,w,h,a0, a1)` with `path.arcTo(x,y,w,h,a0+a1,-a1)`.

Comment: I have updated the MRE

Comment: tried path.arcTo(x,y,w,h,a0+a1,-a1)---replaced painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 6 - 4, 4, 4, 270, 90) with painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 6 - 4, 4, 4, 360, -90).but still not get the expected otput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. I've added comments to indicate how the elements in item 2 relate to those in item 1.

Item 1:

```
painterPath.moveTo(10, 6)
# line 1
painterPath.lineTo(10 + 44.3479, 6)
# arc 1 counter clockwise
painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 6 - 4, 4, 4, 270, 90)
# line 2
painterPath.lineTo(10 + 44.3479 - 2, 6 - 4)
# arc 2 counter clockwise
painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 6 - 6, 4, 4, 0, 90) 
# line 3
painterPath.lineTo(10, 0)
```

Item 2:

```
painterPath.moveTo(10, 0)
# line 3
painterPath.lineTo(10 + 44.3479, 0)
# arc 2 clockwise
painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 6 - 6, 4, 4, 90, -90)
# line 2
painterPath.lineTo(10 + 44.3479 - 2, 6 - 4)
# arc 1 clockwise
painterPath.arcTo(10 + 44.3479 - 6, 6 - 4, 4, 4, 360, -90)
# line 1
painterPath.lineTo(10, 6)
```